# dash.js can't play multiple videos one after the other

Tags: mpeg-dash, dash.js

I'm trying to use dash.js to play some mpeg-dash videos one after the other using the same dash object. I will initialize things like so:

```
var dashPlayer = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
```

Then I will initialize it with my first video like:

```
dashPlayer.initialize(document.getElementById('dashvideoelement'), 'https:urltompegdashvideosource', true);
```

This will cause the video to play the way I want. Once it is over, I would like to reuse this object to play a new video, but subsequent initializations with different url sources do nothing, even if I call `reset()` on the object, where if I then initialize and try `play()`, I get

```
Uncaught You must first call initialize() and set a valid source and view before calling this method
```

Is it not possible to reuse the dash.js object to play different videos? This happens on dash.js versions 3.2.2 and 4.0.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check version 4.1.0. We fixed this here: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/pull/3735. A nightly build of dash.js is available here: https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help!